# Checking if a shape can fit into a space

Tags: java

folks. For the method `public boolean shapeFitsAt(int row, int col, Shape shape)` I'm passing half of the test cases while failing the rest. I feel I'm doing something wrong in the code again, I'm missing something. For example, if I have the following shape of String type:

```
 aaa
 aa.
```

and a space of type String:

```
  ......
  ......
  ......
  ......
  ......
  .....|
```

When I place a shape into the above space at `row = 4` and `col = 3`, it should look like this:

```
  ......
  ......
  ......
  ..aaa.
  ..aa..
  .....|
```

meaning that the shape fits! Whenever the shape's characters collide with space's character other than `'.'` the method returns `false` as the shape would not fit! But I'm failing test cases where the shape should fit!. Could somebody help out? Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.*;

public class CreateSpace implements Space{

    private int height;
    private int width;
    private String layout;
    private char[][] space;
    private Shape originalShape;
    private ArrayList<CreateShape> shapes = new ArrayList<CreateShape>();

    public CreateSpace(int height, int width, char[][] space, String layout)
    {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.space = space;
        this.layout = layout;
    }



    public boolean isFilledAt(int row, int col)
    {

        if(space[row][col] == '.')
            return false;
        else if(row > height || row < height || col > width || col < width)
            return true;
        else            
            return true;
    }

    public boolean shapeFitsAt(int row, int col, Shape shape)
    {

        if(row < 0 || row >= height || col < 0 || col >= width)
            throw new FitItException("Oops! Out of bounds in CreateSpace class! Go and check!");

        else if(isFilledAt(row, col)==true)
            throw new FitItException("The space position is already filled out with a wall or a character. GO CHECK CreateSpace class!");

        else
        {
            for(int r = 0; r < height; r++)
                for(int c = 0; c < width; c++)
                {
                    if(space[r][c] == '.')
                        return true;
                }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Example of a failing test:

```
  @Test(timeout=1000) public void space_fits2(){
    String shLayout =
      "aaa\n"+
      "";
    int row=0, col=1;
    String spLayout =
      "|....|\n"+
      "......\n"+
      "..||..\n"+
      "......\n"+
      "|....|\n"+
      "";
    boolean expect = true;
    char dc = getDisplayChar(shLayout);
    Space space = FitIt.makeSpace(spLayout);
    Shape shape = FitIt.makeShape(shLayout,dc);
    boolean actual = space.shapeFitsAt(row,col,shape);
    if(actual != expect){
      failFmt("\nshapeFitsAt() problem\nExpect: %s\nActual: %s\nrow: %s; col %s\n\n%s\n%s",
              expect,actual,row,col,shape,space);
    }
  }
```

Comment: shouldn't your last else return false?  otherwise, what's the point of checking whether the shape extends outside the known area?

Comment: that's what it is doing in shapeFitsAt,@ScottSosna

Comment: What do you mean, @ScottSosna, by "what's the point of checking whether the shape extends outside the known area"?

Comment: Could you provide an example of falling test?

Comment: Sure, @PavelRudko, it's in the above code

Comment: IS THERE ANYONE who could help???

Comment: @John - keep it down. People have other things to do besides help you out, and it is rude to SHOUT on the internets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking if a difficult condition is true, you should be eager to return false as soon as you find a problem, and only if you find no problems should you finally return true.

This snippet returns `true` as soon as it finds a `'.'` (as @Scott Sosna points out) - and therefore, the nested loops never actually get executed:

```
   {
        for(int r = 0; r < height; r++)
            for(int c = 0; c < width; c++)
            {
                if(space[r][c] == '.')
                    return true;
            }
        return false;
   }
```

This would have been much better:

```
   {
        for(int r = 0; r < height; r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < width; c++) {
                if (shape.isFilledAt(r, c) && space[r+row][c+col] != '.') {
                    return false; // eager to fail
                }
            }
        }
        return true; // slow to succeed: only if it never failed
   }
```

Notice the `shape.isFilledAt(r, c)` -- if you do not look at the `shape` to check if it fits (and in your code, you forget to use shape in any way within `shapeFitsAt`), then how can you expect your program to work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @tucuxi. I did not want to be rude by commenting but I've been stuck in this method for almost 3 days straight and still cannot finish it. The code that you've provided gives me same results, i.e. Im still failing some test cases.

Comment: That is because your code has more problems than those I pointed to above. For example, in your test code, you write `boolean actual = space.shapeFitsAt(row,col,shape);` - that is, you only test if it fits in at that position. Shouldn't you attempt to place the shape in all positions? (iterate over all combinations of row, col not outside the bounds?)

Answer (score 0):

The only place where the dimensions of the area are checked is the else-if condition, which if true returns true.  However, since the final else also returns true, it degrades into:

```
 public boolean isFilledAt(int row, int col)
    {
        if(space[row][col] == '.')
            return false;
        else            
            return true;
    }
```

or

```
public boolean isFilledAt(int row, int col)
{
   return space[row][col] != '.';
}
```

which does not take into account the size of the area.